# A proof of a result in Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I am looking for a proof of this fact: let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic function, $f\in L^1(-\pi,\pi),$ and let $a_k,b_k$ be its Fourier coefficients. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{|a_k|+|b_k|}<\infty,$ then the Fourier series of $f$ converges to $f.$

I know that the Fourier series of $f$ converges (uniformly) to a certain $g$ because of Weierstrass M-Test, but how can I prove that $g=f?$

Comment: It boils down to proving that if all Fourier coefficients of a function are zero, then that function is zero almost everywhere. Is that known? If not, what sort of theory can you throw at it?

Comment: Do I have to consider the function $f-g$ and prove that its Fourier coefficient are zero?

Comment: Basically. But there's not much to prove, that $g$'s Fourier coefficients are the $a_k$ resp. $b_k$ is rather easy.

Comment: I have a proof of the fact that if all Fourier coefficients of a function are zero  function is zero only if f is continuous. How can this result be generalised for a Function in $L^1?$

Comment: Well. If $h \in L^1(-\pi,\pi)$ is such that all Fourier coefficients vanish, by linearity it follows that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(x) T(x)\,dx = 0$ for every trigonometric polynomial $T$. By Stone-Weierstraß, or by Fejér's theorem, it follows that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(x) q(x)\,dx = 0$ for every $2\pi$-periodic $q \in C([-\pi,\pi])$. By the [fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations), it follows that $h(x) = 0$ almost everywhere, and that means $h = 0$ in $L^1$. How much of that theory have you ready to use?

Comment: The fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations has been made at lesson, fejer's theorem is one of the next topics, while i know Stone weierstrass only with polinomials, not with trigonometric polinomals

Comment: We can avoid that, since "all continuous functions" is much more than we need for the FLCV. Consider $2\pi$-periodic $q \in C^k([-\pi,\pi])$ for $k \geqslant 1$. It's easy to see (via integration by parts) that the Fourier series of such a $q$ converges uniformly to $q$, so we get $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} h(x)q(x)\,dx = 0$ for those $q$, and that's (still far more than) enough for the FLCV.